# Djnago Admin : Country/State/City Dropdown

Tags: django, django-admin, chained-select

I'm trying to do a chained dropdown of Country/State/City in Django Admin

I know there is lot of post about this, And this is very basic problem. Is there any good solution or builtin solution that Im missing, Can anyone tell, How to solve it or guide in proper direction?

Comment: You can use django-autocomplete-light package for chained dropdown.

Comment: you can read this article https://technosaurus.in/blog/5/implement-dependent-chained-dropdown-list-with-django-admin/